# Ace's instance not defined in custom worker

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ace-editor

I was following this [tutorial](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/ace-javascript-target.md) to create my custom worker in order to validate syntaxes.

My custom mode creates an instance of my custom worker and returns it to ace.

The problem is that I don't have access to requirejs and ace global instance in my custom worker so I can't really do anything.

My code looks exactly like the one in the tutorial

What could be the problem that causes me to lose ace's value in my worker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User `ace.js` from `ace-builds/src/noconflict` instead of `ace-builds/src/`